# Flutter Setting initialScrollOffset on a large list becomes laggy and very slow

Tags: listview, flutter

I am trying to save the list position so when the user closes the app and come back to it, they can pick up where they left off. for a small list, this works fine, but on a larger list, setting the initialscrolloffset hangs the UI (very slow) for a few seconds.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Long List';

    ScrollController _controller = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 29900);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          controller: _controller,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('${items[index]}'),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
From https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12319#issuecomment-569296423 
You can use `scrollable_positioned_list` 
It provide `jumpTo` 
code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter_widgets/flutter_widgets.dart';
...
itemScrollController.jumpTo(index: 150);
...
Widget list(Orientation orientation) => ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
            itemCount: numberOfItems,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => item(index, orientation),
            itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
            itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
            reverse: reversed,
            scrollDirection: orientation == Orientation.portrait
                ? Axis.vertical
                : Axis.horizontal,
          );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter_widgets/flutter_widgets.dart';

const numberOfItems = 5001;
const minItemHeight = 20.0;
const maxItemHeight = 150.0;
const scrollDuration = Duration(seconds: 2);

/// Example widget that uses [ScrollablePositionedList].
///
/// Shows a [ScrollablePositionedList] along with the following controls:
///   - Buttons to jump or scroll to certain items in the list.
///   - Slider to control the alignment of the items being scrolled or jumped
///   to.
///   - A checkbox to reverse the list.
///
/// If the device this example is being used on is in portrait mode, the list
/// will be vertically scrollable, and if the device is in landscape mode, the
/// list will be horizontally scrollable.
class ScrollablePositionedListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollablePositionedListPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScrollablePositionedListPageState createState() =>
      _ScrollablePositionedListPageState();
}

class _ScrollablePositionedListPageState
    extends State<ScrollablePositionedListPage> {
  /// Controller to scroll or jump to a particular item.
  final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();

  /// Listener that reports the position of items when the list is scrolled.
  final ItemPositionsListener itemPositionsListener =
      ItemPositionsListener.create();
  List<double> itemHeights;
  List<Color> itemColors;
  bool reversed = false;

  /// The alignment to be used next time the user scrolls or jumps to an item.
  double alignment = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final heightGenerator = Random(328902348);
    final colorGenerator = Random(42490823);
    itemHeights = List<double>.generate(
        numberOfItems,
        (int _) =>
            heightGenerator.nextDouble() * (maxItemHeight - minItemHeight) +
            minItemHeight);
    itemColors = List<Color>.generate(
        numberOfItems,
        (int _) =>
            Color(colorGenerator.nextInt(pow(2, 32) - 1)).withOpacity(1));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Material(
        child: OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) => Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: list(orientation),
              ),
              positionsView,
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      scrollControlButtons,
                      jumpControlButtons,
                      alignmentControl,
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget get alignmentControl => Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Alignment: '),
          SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: Slider(
              value: alignment,
              onChanged: (double value) => setState(() => alignment = value),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );

  Widget list(Orientation orientation) => ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
        itemCount: numberOfItems,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => item(index, orientation),
        itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
        itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
        reverse: reversed,
        scrollDirection: orientation == Orientation.portrait
            ? Axis.vertical
            : Axis.horizontal,
      );

  Widget get positionsView => ValueListenableBuilder<Iterable<ItemPosition>>(
        valueListenable: itemPositionsListener.itemPositions,
        builder: (context, positions, child) {
          int min;
          int max;
          if (positions.isNotEmpty) {
            // Determine the first visible item by finding the item with the
            // smallest trailing edge that is greater than 0.  i.e. the first
            // item whose trailing edge in visible in the viewport.
            min = positions
                .where((ItemPosition position) => position.itemTrailingEdge > 0)
                .reduce((ItemPosition min, ItemPosition position) =>
                    position.itemTrailingEdge < min.itemTrailingEdge
                        ? position
                        : min)
                .index;
            // Determine the last visible item by finding the item with the
            // greatest leading edge that is less than 1.  i.e. the last
            // item whose leading edge in visible in the viewport.
            max = positions
                .where((ItemPosition position) => position.itemLeadingEdge < 1)
                .reduce((ItemPosition max, ItemPosition position) =>
                    position.itemLeadingEdge > max.itemLeadingEdge
                        ? position
                        : max)
                .index;
          }
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: Text('First Item: ${min ?? ''}')),
              Expanded(child: Text('Last Item: ${max ?? ''}')),
              const Text('Reversed: '),
              Checkbox(
                  value: reversed,
                  onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() {
                        reversed = value;
                      }))
            ],
          );
        },
      );

  Widget get scrollControlButtons => Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('scroll to'),
          scrollButton(0),
          scrollButton(5),
          scrollButton(10),
          scrollButton(100),
          scrollButton(1000),
          scrollButton(5000),
        ],
      );

  Widget get jumpControlButtons => Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('jump to'),
          jumpButton(0),
          jumpButton(5),
          jumpButton(10),
          jumpButton(100),
          jumpButton(1000),
          jumpButton(5000),
        ],
      );

  Widget scrollButton(int value) => GestureDetector(
        key: ValueKey<String>('Scroll$value'),
        onTap: () => scrollTo(value),
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Text('$value')),
      );

  Widget jumpButton(int value) => GestureDetector(
        key: ValueKey<String>('Jump$value'),
        onTap: () => jumpTo(value),
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Text('$value')),
      );

  void scrollTo(int index) => itemScrollController.scrollTo(
      index: index,
      duration: scrollDuration,
      curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
      alignment: alignment);

  void jumpTo(int index) =>
      itemScrollController.jumpTo(index: index, alignment: alignment);

  /// Generate item number [i].
  Widget item(int i, Orientation orientation) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? itemHeights[i] : null,
      width: orientation == Orientation.landscape ? itemHeights[i] : null,
      child: Container(
        color: itemColors[i],
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Item $i'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ScrollablePositionedListPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, ScrollablePositionedList worked for my use case perfectly! the issue with listview is that when you use jumpto, it has to build all the previous items in order to calculate and scroll to the specified position. which is fine on a shorter list but causes serious performance issues on larger lists.