# Flutter how to group a list from firebase based on a certain value

Tags: firebase, listview, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, grouped-list

I have a firebase database with 2 relevant collections: "products" and "categories".

I would like to show the products in a listview grouped by their category.

In every product document there is a 'category' field which is the category id.

Right now I have this code to just create the listview:

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildProductItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
        itemCount: (snapshot.data.documents.length),
      );
    }
)
```

I've tried a few things (like this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178292/flutter-how-to-create-a-list-with-header-from-a-firebase-object)), but I want to keep it within the StreamBuilder so the data will still update live.

How would I group them so I can show a title above every group and the products corresponding to that title underneath?

Answer (score 3):

Actually fixing it was quite easy with the link to the question I firstly provided.
You can just use a GroupedListView [(package)](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list) instead of the Listview.builder.
Don't know why it took me so long to get that :p
Hopefully this helps someone else in the future :)

````
StreamBuilder(
   stream: Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
     return GroupedListView(
       elements: snapshot.data.documents,
       groupBy: (element) => element['category'],
       groupSeparatorBuilder: _buildGroupSeparator,
       itemBuilder: buildProductItem,
       order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,
     );
   }
),```
````